# How to use typing hints with an optional first parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

#### Introduction

I have a function that is either called as `fun(start, stop, divisors)` or `fun(stop, divisors)`.

1. I want to call the parameters in this specific order.
2. I want to implement it in a way that does not give any type-hinting errors.

If I ease on any of these two restrictions, the implementation is easy. For instance, easing the restriction on the order can be done like so:

```
def fun(stop: int, divisors: List[int], start: int=0) -> int:
    ...
    return 0

fun(5, [1, 2, 3])
fun(5, [1, 2, 3], start=2)
```

Or easing on the type hints is shown in the file below, but with a proper ordering of arguments.

#### Question

How should I write my code so that my function arguments are:

1. *statically typed*;
2. *in the particular order: `(start[optional], stop, divisors)`*;
3. *gives 0 mypy errors?*

#### Attempts

```
import typing
from typing import Union, Optional

Start = int
Stop = int
Divisor = int
Divisors = list[Divisor]


@typing.overload
def fun1(x: Start, y: Stop, divisors: Divisors) -> int:
    ...


@typing.overload
def fun1(y: Stop, divisors: Divisors) -> int:
    ...


def fun1(*args) -> int:
    if (arglen := len(args)) not in [2, 3]:
        raise TypeError("Function expected 2 or 3 arguments, got", arglen)
    if arglen == 2:
        args = [0] + list(args)
    start, stop, divisors = args
    return 0


def fun2(x, y, divisors) -> int:
    if divisors is None:
        start, stop, divisors = 0, x, y
    else:
        start, stop = x, y
    return 0


def fun3(*args) -> int:
    if (arglen := len(args)) == 3:
        start: Stop = args[0]
        stop: int = args[1]
        divisors: Divisors = args[2]
    elif arglen == 2:
        start: Stop = 0
        stop: int = args[0]
        divisors: Divisors = args[1]
    else:
        raise TypeError(
            f"Too {'few' if arglen == 0 else 'many'} values to unpack (2-3), got",
            arglen,
        )
    return 0


def fun4(*args) -> int:
    if (arglen := len(args)) == 3:
        pass
    elif arglen == 2:
        args = [0] + list(args)
    else:
        raise TypeError(
            f"Too {'few' if arglen == 0 else 'many'} values to unpack (2-3), got",
            arglen,
        )
    start: Stop = args[0]
    stop: int = args[1]
    divisors: Divisors = args[2]
    return 0
```

**[Output from mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=9a1255176bea7e69138aed78af5fec40)**:

```
typing_test_PE_001.py:20: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 1
typing_test_PE_001.py:20: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2
typing_test_PE_001.py:24: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[int]", variable has type "Tuple[Any, ...]")
typing_test_PE_001.py:43: error: Name "start" already defined on line 39
typing_test_PE_001.py:44: error: Name "stop" already defined on line 40
typing_test_PE_001.py:45: error: Name "divisors" already defined on line 41
typing_test_PE_001.py:58: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[int]", variable has type "Tuple[Any, ...]")
Found 7 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: `def fun(arg1: int, arg2: Union[int, List[int]], arg3: Optional[int] = None)`?

Comment: You'll never get statically typed function arguments as long as you're writing your code in Python. Your *easy implementation* example is more readable and Pythonic than any answer you're likely to get.

Comment: @Woodford you can get static type checking in Python using type hints and a type checker like `mypy`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, but it's not enforced at runtime.

Comment: @Woodford huh? Static type checking isn't supposed to be enforced at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how [`slice` is hinted](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/7edad1034e7728bfbb74d29de6ae792d6f1275e8/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L699):

```
class slice(object):
    start: Any
    step: Any
    stop: Any
    @overload
    def __init__(self, stop: Any) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, start: Any, stop: Any, step: Any = ...) -> None: ...
    __hash__: None  # type: ignore
    def indices(self, len: SupportsIndex) -> Tuple[int, int, int]: ...
```

and [`range`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/7edad1034e7728bfbb74d29de6ae792d6f1275e8/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L903)

```
class range(Sequence[int]):
    start: int
    stop: int
    step: int
    @overload
    def __init__(self, stop: SupportsIndex) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, start: SupportsIndex, stop: SupportsIndex, step: SupportsIndex = ...) -> None: ...
    [...]
```

Basically, you hint the two overloaded versions separately, one with the optional first parameter and one without. (So basically, your Attempt #2.)

```
from typing import overload, List

@overload
def fun(start: int, stop: int, divisors: List[int]):
    ...

@overload
def fun(stop: int, divisors: List[int]):
    ...

def fun(start, stop, divisors=None):
    if divisors is None:
        divisors = stop
        stop = start
        start = 0

    ...

fun(1, 2, [1,2,3])  # OK
fun(2, [1,2,3])  # OK
```

If you like, you can also make both variants accept positional arguments only:

```
# e.g.
def fun(start, stop, divisors=None, /):
    ...
```

Comment: you may have to use casts in `fun` to get `mypy` happy in a general case, maybe not here I haven't checked but....

Comment: I think the key issue here is that `mypy` was complaining because `def fun(*args)` couldn't accept the overloads... just to point out specifically the issue with the OP's.

Comment: I tried to find a solution using overloads but couldn't find one MyPy would accept with the --strict setting applied (this fails using --strict due to the lack of type hints for the concrete implementation)

Comment: @chepner Great answer! Is there any reason `mypy` complains when I specify the return type? E.g changing to `def fun(start, stop, divisors=None) -> int:` raises the error `Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2`.

Comment: Ahhh, this fixes itself if we make both variants accep accept positional arguments only.  See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6187. Seems one either has to make the argument overloads anonymous/positional only (using `__callable_1` etc), or add **kwargs to implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I probably shouldn't have put in such a terse afterthought. I suspect that both the overloads and the implementation should be consistent regarding positional-only arguments. If you do specify the return type, it should probably be on the two overload versions, but not the implementation.

Comment: @chepner I'm afraid mypy --strict complains if you omit a single return annotation, even if the function in question has a return annotation in every single signature laid out using `@overload`

Comment: Hm, I don't know enough about the intricacies to tell if that's a bug, or a trade-off, or a necessity.